# XMLSignature newXMLSignature return the same instance

Tags: java, xml

i'm trying to developer a signature builder for brazilians fiscals notes. When my system sign twice diffentes xmls files in the same scope, the seconde fail in signature validation.
I presume the problem is on my method to build the signature.

```
public void build(Element elementToSign, Element parentElement, Certificate certificate, PrivateKey privateKey) {
        try {
            List<Reference> refList = newReferenceList(elementToSign);
            SignedInfo signedInfo = newSignedInfo(refList);
            KeyInfo keyInfo = keyInfoBuilder.newKeyInfo(certificate);
            DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(privateKey, parentElement);
            XMLSignature signature = signatureFactory.newXMLSignature(signedInfo, keyInfo);
            logger.info("Assinatura: {}, keyInfo: {}, dsc: {}, signature: {}",
                    new Object[]{ signature, keyInfo, dsc, signature });
            signature.sign(dsc);
            logger.debug(" Primeiro digest value encontrado é {}.", ((Reference) signature.getSignedInfo().getReferences().get(0)).getDigestValue());
            InputStreamReader isr = 
                new InputStreamReader(signature.getSignedInfo().getCanonicalizedData());
            char[] cbuf = new char[1024];
            while (isr.read(cbuf, 0, 1024) != -1) {
                System.out.print(cbuf);
            }
            System.out.println();
            logger.debug("Elemento <{}> assinado e inserido em <{}>.", elementToSign.getTagName(), parentElement.getTagName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Impossível construir assinatura, ", e);
        }
    }
```

In my debug steps i'm see the signatureFactory.newXMLSignature(signedInfo, keyInfo) returns the same instance, somebody can help with newXMLSingature don't instanciate a new object?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "the same scope"?

Comment: sorry about that description. But my problem is like that, this method is the signature core. In a external method, if i call the signature twice for the same xml document, i have the differents values for DigestValue e SignatureValue.

Comment: Like this example
{Document xmlConsulta = this.carregaDocConsultaLoteRpsSp(doc, municipio);
//Sign the xmlDocument
  Document xmlEnvioAssinado = this.getNfseComunicacaoService().assinaLoteSp(xmlConsulta);
Document xmlEnvioAssinado2 = this.getNfseComunicacaoService().assinaLoteSp(xmlConsulta);}
The documents xmlEnvioAssinado and xmlEnvioAssinado2 has differents signature values.